# Pandas force one-to-one merge on column containing duplicate keys

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I have two `Dataframes`, df1:

```
| ID        | Invoice   |
-------------------------
| X\191     | 4         |
| R\192     | 4         |
| 733       | 1         |
| X215      | 3         |
| BL000002  | 3         |
```

df2:

```
| ID        | Invoice   |
-------------------------
| X191      | 4         |
| X215      | 3         |
| BL000002  | 3         |
```

And I should merge them one to one to get:

```
| ID        | Invoice   | ID        |
-------------------------------------
| X\191     | 4         | X191      |
| X\192     | 4         |           |
| 733       | 1         |           |
| X215      | 3         | X215      |
| BL000002  | 3         | BL000002  |
```

But when I do a outer merge I get repeated values

```
import pandas as pd
dict1 = {"ID": ["X\\191","R\\192","733","X215","BL000002"], "Inv": [4,4,1,3,3]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict1)

dict2 = {"ID": ["X191","X215","BL000002"], "Inv": [4,3,3]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict2)

some_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on = 'Inv', how='outer')
```

The output looks like:

```
    ID_x    Inv    ID_y
X\191       4      X191
X\192       4      X191
733         1       NaN
X215        3      X215
X215        3  BL000002
BL000002    3      X215
BL000002    3  BL000002
```

How can I merge such that I get it to join one to one and not mix and match.

I can't use any other column in the merge as they will vary in the actual data.

**Edit and explanation**
I'm sorry. I was't clear enough. The column ID isn't consistent. I can't promise if it'll be a substring always either. But the invoice values must be the same. This was entered by human over a year and there are around 15K rows. I need to order them such that the ones with the same Invoice value comes next to each other, so it's easier to manually validate when something is missing from one of the dataframes (originally a excel sheet)

Comment: Maybe try somthing like this: ```>>> pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on='Inv', right_on='Inv', how='outer')
```

Comment: Why are you joining on `Inv`? Shouldn't you be joining on `ID`?

Comment: @Mortz No because I've mentioned I can't use ID. In the actual data-set I have already grouped IDs and inside a group I have `"Invoice Value", "Date", 'InvNumber"` Every thing except "Invoice Value" is a variable between two `df`s.

Comment: @IhorVoronin I tried that. I get the same result. How did you get a different result?

Comment: @clmno, seems dataFrame has been edited now!

Comment: @pygo Yes, I edited it to make the problem clearer. Except for one column the rest can't be depended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an additional `cumcount`-based column:

```
u = df1.assign(Cnt=df1.groupby('Inv').cumcount())
v = df2.assign(Cnt=df2.groupby('Inv').cumcount())
u.merge(v, on=['Inv', 'Cnt'], how='left').drop('Cnt', 1)

       ID_x  Inv      ID_y
0     X\191    4      X191
1     R\192    4       NaN
2       733    1       NaN
3      X215    3      X215
4  BL000002    3  BL000002
```

Comment: Hey coldspeed, are you not missing a parenthesis `(`?

Comment: This looks like the answer. I'm running it on the actual data set. Will get back in a while

Comment: You have a typo at `u.merge(v), on=['Inv', 'Cnt'], how='left').drop('Cnt', 1)` it should be `u.merge(v, on=['Inv', 'Cnt'], how='left').drop('Cnt', 1)`

Comment: @clmno thank you for catching it. The solution works but I made copy paste errors while writing the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think a simple list lookup will do the trick:

```
df1['new_id'] = df1.apply(lambda row: row['ID'] if row['ID'] in df2['ID'].tolist() else "", axis=1)

     ID  Invoice new_id
0  X191        4   X191
1  X192        4       
2  X212        1       
3  X215        3   X215
4  X319        3   X319
```

After you find the things to remove you can do (I assume ID has `\`, `.`, '@'):

```
df['ID'] = df['ID'].str.replace(r'\\|\.|@', '')
```

Comment: I've edited the question for better understanding of the situation. Please have a look. Basically from your answer, I can't depend on ID because they are almost never the same (could be a substring, but I can't be sure).

Comment: can you not preprocess the ID in df1 ?

Comment: Yes I can. How do I get going doing that? The actual df will have a `supplier ID `that I'm using to group them. Then all I currently have left is the  `Invoice Value`. I can maybe work on building a better `Invoice Number` (which is what I called ID here in the question)

Comment: in df1, you should look at ID values, may be print more IDs and see what more punctuation marks are found, for now I can see, ID values have `\` in them, there would be more, once you find them you can do the command I added in answer.,

Comment: Thank you! But coldspeed's answer is pretty cool and solved it just the way I wanted it to. I'm actually awed by his/her solution

Answer (score 0):

Try Below:

You're looking for `pandas.merge_asof`. It allows you to combine 2 DataFrames on a key, in this case time, without the requirement that they are an exact match. You can choose a direction for prioritizing the match, but in this case it's obvious that you want nearest

```
>>> pd.merge_asof(df2.sort_values('Inv'), df1.sort_values('Inv'), on='Inv', direction='nearest')
  ID_x  Inv  ID_y 
0  215    3  X319
1  319    3  X319
2  191    4  X192
```

look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50434160/python-pandas-compare-two-data-frames-along-one-column-and-return-content-of-r) , Borrowed from @
ALollz